# Connection error when using pymongo with minikube

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, replicaset

I'm configuring my Mongo application with PyMongo in a replica set setup, but I'm seeing this error logs.

```json
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T08:34:15.914+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21313,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup","attr":{"error":{"code":47,"codeName":"NoMatchingDocument","errmsg":"Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset"}}}
```

Right now I'm configuring the replica set at startup, like

```
var config = {
        "_id": "project",
        "version": 1,
        "members": [
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "host": "project:27017",
                "priority": 2
            }
            ,
            {
                 "_id": 2,
                 "host": "project2:27017",
                 "priority": 1
             }
            {
                 "_id": 3,
                 "host": "project3:27017",
                 "priority": 1
            }
        ]
    };
```

`rs.initiate(config);`

Looking at this error it looks to me like this is expecting a document, maybe the same that I wrote above somewhere.
However, I've seen around that the previous configuration should be correct.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to write that file somewhere?